# How to configure so I can install more than two apps from GluonHQ - JavaFX

Tags: android, gluon-mobile

I made two applications for mobile use:

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/BooK

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/JLogger

When I install BooK, it just works perfect. But when I install JLogger, then Android says that the application did not become installed. If I uninstall BooK and then install JLogger, I cannot install BooK.

Is there any way to configure so I can have them installed at the same time?
I got license for JLogger, but it seems to take very long time to get a free license for BooK. 
Also I wonder if it's possible to remove the G-icon in Android? Every application made with GluonHQ framework generates an mobile application with a G-icon, even if I changed the G-icon at the menu banner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**package name**

If you check the `AndroidManifest.xml` for both apps, both have the same `package` name:

```
package="se.danielmartensson"
```

Every app (Android/iOS) has to be defined by an [unique](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) package name (or bundleId on iOS):

> beware that, once the APK is compiled, the `package` attribute also represents your app's universally unique application ID.

Just change it to something like:

```
package="se.danielmartensson.book"

package="se.danielmartensson.jlogger"
```

Save, remove your existing apps (BooK or JLogger), and install them again. You should have two apps now.

**Gluon Mobile license**

Gluon Mobile [licenses](https://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/buy/) are applied per developer, not per app. You can use the same license in both apps.

In case you apply for OSS license, it is [intended](https://gluonhq.com/programs/free-gluon-licenses/open-source-license-request/) to be used only on a single OSS project, but if both projects are related, I don't see any issue on using it in both.

As an aside, you shouldn't commit your license files to online public repositories.

**Icons**

The default template that you get when you use the Gluon plugin for your IDE provides a default set of icons.

You can replace this set with your own. Just create the set of icons according to the given resolution (in this [folder](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/BooK/tree/master/BooK/BooKApp/src/android/res)for Android, this [one](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/BooK/tree/master/BooK/BooKApp/src/ios/assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset) for iOS).

Comment: Thank you very much. So how can I hide the license number? Should I just remove it and write in the ReadMe that if they want to remove the nag screen, they need to ask for a license fro them self?

Comment: The license can't be shared publicly. You should just have it locally in your repository, so you can use it for testing and building the apps for deploying. Those that want to test your project, will either get the nag screen (free tier) or ask for a valid license, indeed.